# Where is Soft Delete for Easy Table ?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-using-soft-delete/

So I'm reading the article, updated 07/21/2016, and it shows a Soft Delete checkbox for when you create an Easy Table.

[image]

So I go to my Easy Table, and when I try creating one, I don't see the Soft Delete checkbox anywhere.

[image]

I also tried searching for Soft Delete in Azure Classic Portal, but the interface is not accepting any more Mobile Services. Instead, they redirect you to use Mobile Apps.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soft Delete is automatically enabled for Easy Tables.